# Waiting for boolean value to execute code (MPMoviePlayerController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using a MPMoviePlayerController, the problem is that while the video is being processed it's shown a black screen, so what I'm trying to do is to wait for isPreparedToPlay to become true to add the subview.

It will be something like this:

```
    MPMoviePlayerController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                           initWithContentURL:url];

    (wait for controller.isPreparedToPlay){
            [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
            [controller setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
            [controller prepareToPlay];
    }
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the various notifications that the MPMoviePlayerController posts?

Comment: Oh didn't noticed about MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification !! Will try with that one, I though about doing it with MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification but the first one seems to be what I'm looking for!